# How do I get a list of pointers to existing objects in a view?

Tags: objective-c

I am writing an app that has about 100 `UIButton` objects in a view.  I want to manipulate the visual properties of those buttons without the user necessarily hitting them.  If I create the buttons in Xcode pre-runtime, how do I get the pointers for each of those buttons at runtime?  Is there are register somewhere?

Even if I enum a list of all objects on the view and then query their class type and properties to find just the buttons I want, that would suffice.

Should I be using a Collection View?

I suppose if I create the buttons in runtime, I can store their pointers in an array as I create them, but is there another way to do it?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can access all child-views (like UIButtons) which are in this view (if they are in other view in this view you will need to use recurency) by accessing UIView property **subviews**.

```
//UIView
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews
```

like this:

```
NSArray *subviews = myView.subviews;

for(NSObject *uiobject in subviews){
    if([uiobject isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
       // alter your buttons here
    }//if there are for example uiViews you can try use recurrency 
}
```